# Sizeof function definition in a system

Tags: programming-languages, c

Why sizeof(int) and sizeof(int *) takes different value in a system? I mean generally size of integer is 4 B, but size of integer pointer is 8 B. But why they cannot take same value, although their return type is same?

Comment: What do you mean by "their return type is the same"?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I'm not sure it matters, since this question is purely about a feature of the C language, which is off-topic, here. But I agree this should be clarified when the question is asked on [so].

Comment: I mean one is integer variable and another is integer pointer. Both integer type .

Comment: They're *not* the same type. One is an integer, another is a pointer, i.e., a memory address. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming).

Comment: @DavidRicherby This is a rather general question, which has little to do with C. It is about the difference between pointers and what they point at.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51717359/5376789

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An integer is a value, whereas a pointer to an integer is a *pointer*, that is, a memory address. In most systems, all pointers have the same size, but the objects they point to can have different sizes. For example, in your systems pointers are 8 bytes long, whereas integers come in various sizes — possibly from 1 byte up to 8 bytes.

You might be misled by the specific quirky syntax of C, which allows declarations of the form

```
int a, *b;
```

This declares an integer `a` and a *pointer* `b`. This is just a confusing feature of C syntax.

Comment: "whereas integers come in various sizes — possibly from 1 byte up to 8 bytes.

"-Can you tell me how?

Comment: This is already getting to be specific to the C programming language. C has several integer datatypes, which generally have different sizes, though the exact sizes are implementation-dependent. Any good text on C would cover these.

Comment: You mean size of integer can be 2B or 4B or 8B in 64bit system? Then pointer size also can vary, right?

Comment: On modern systems pointer sizes don't vary. There's certainly no reason for them to vary depending on what they are pointing at. See [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315311/what-is-a-long-pointer) for the situation in the past. The available integer sizes depend on the system. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Basic_types).

Comment: Sizeof(int) is entirely up to the C compiler except it must be >= 1. It could be 42. Which would be unusual, but entirely possible.

Comment: Yuval: on a C implementation  with 64 bit pointer and 32 bit char sizeof (pointer) would be only 2. There have been machines in the past where sizeof(char*) > sizeof (int*), because the smallest addressable unit was larger than char.